# C program: Breaking an int into an int array[]

Tags: c, arrays

So I'm working on a Zeller's Rule c program, trying to break a 4 digit int that represents the year of a specific date into 2 different int variables containing the first 2 digits and last 2 digits of said year.

```
void main()
{
    int day, month, year;
    .
    .
    .
    printf("Enter a Year: ");
    scanf("%i",&year);
    .
    .
    .
    int data, i;    
    int split[3];
    for(i=3 ; i>=0 ; i--)           //Problem is in the loop
    {
        data = year % 10;
        split[i] = data;
        year /= 10; 
        printf("Data%i: %i, should be %i\n", i, split[i], data);
    }
}
```

The above code outputs: (int year = 1234)

```
Data3: 0, should be 4
Data2: 0, should be 0
Data1: 0, should be 0
Data0: 0, should be 0
```

However, if i modify the loop labeled as the problem above as:

```
int data, i;    
int split[3];
for(i=3 ; i>=0 ; i--)      //Data is all there, correctly
{                          //Problem arises when I try to store to my array
    data = year % 10;
    year /= 10; 
    printf("Data%i: should be %i\n", i, data);
}
```

output of above code changes: (int year = 1234)

```
Data3: should be 4
Data2: should be 3
Data1: should be 2
Data0: should be 1
```

I am completely lost as to why the program 0's out everything as soon as I try to put the data that IS THERE into my array.  Been giving me a headache for hours as I obviously have no idea what the problem is.

Comment: WEll in your first loop you access an invalid index. You try to access `split[i]` where `i = 3;` but only `[0], [1], [2]` are vlaid indexes for an array declared as `int split[3]`

Comment: `void main` **RAAAAAAAAAAAARRRRRRRRRRRRRRRGGGGGGGGGGGGGGHHHHHHHH**

Comment: Ya, i'll be the first to admit that was a super stupid mistake.....I was under the impression that int split[3]; initialized an array of split[0], split[1], split[2], and split[3].....guess I'm just crazy, lol. Thanks for the help

Comment: @pmg, c is the oldest programming language I've stepped into, and everything else I code in has voids, sorry if it's not the legit old-school way to c-program, lol, it works

Comment: @Stranger: that's why it's so very bad! It works because your compiler implementation tries to be helpful and breaks the rules. Someday you have to use a unhelpful implementation to control the laser beam in a spaceship and the laser fires during the demo killing everybody on board :)

Comment: @Stranger: Use this and never ANYTHING else again: `int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {}`.

Comment: @nightcracker: and i assume that goes hand in hand with return 0;?

Comment: @Stranger: If you want to acknowledge the OS of a successful execution of your program, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 cells in your spit array (`int split[3]`), but you assign 4 times into it:

```
for(i=3 ; i>=0 ; i--)
```

change it to `int split[4]`.

Comment: That was a super stupid mistake.....I was under the impression that int split[3]; initialized an array of split[0], split[1], split[2], and split[3].....guess I'm just crazy, lol. Thanks for the help